# I need help animating multiple rigid body hinge joints

Tags: animation, objects, physics, constraints, rigid-body-simulation

I need to animate a hinge mechanism with multiple other dynamic hinge joints following in sequence to the original.

[image][image]

I have no problem animating the first hinge mechanism.

[image][image]

However, when I add more hinge constraints to the original mesh,[image]

the animation breaks apart like so.

[image]

**Things I have tried:**

Altering rigid body collision settings.

Altering the angle of the empty containing the rigid body relationship.

Altering the parent relationships amongst the objects involved.

**Files**

MULTI_HINGE OBJECT

https://drive.google.com/open?id=10gEugUDgIC-xrCC2Y8tFyysSu2gT5tV2

SINGLE HINGE OBJECT

https://drive.google.com/open?id=12kYQTq2pDsGzSlwUroCrDcyR8KYgqJQS

**Any insight would be appreciated. Thank you**

Answer (score 1):

You have a cube in the first layer that is bouncing off the physics of the arm. Delete that cube and you'll be fine.[image]